In Visual Studio, can I only show the Class Methods in the Editor Navigation Member List?
I would like to only see the methods in the member list (See screenshot).  I don't need to see the class fields.  If that is not possible can I group the methods at the top arranged in alphabetical order.
Thank you.

This would be sufficient.  This screenshot is from another post.


What window is that?  Is that the search bar in the editor?  It is hard to understand why you would ever want to hide anything in that list.  It's just an index.  Also, your second screenshot is obviously from a different class.

After my testing, I found that in Visual Studio, by default, it is not possible to display only class methods and exclude fields or other types of members in the editor navigation member list. The screenshot you provided from another post should be the effect achieved by installing some extensions or plug-ins.

This list above the editor window is officially called Navigation bar. Just in case you would need to find it in the Options or google for it.
As others noted, there's no way to customize it out of the box without any extension.
Option 1
You can achieve what you need with the Document Outline window (View - Other Windows - Document Outline). It allows you to change the sort order at the top. The Sort By Type will do the trick:

Make sure you have enabled this option.  Go to Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced. Scroll to the very bottom and select Enable document outline. Do this also for other languages you need.
Option 2
Even more options for sorting and grouping can be found in the Object Browser (View - Object Browser) with a right-click:

Option 3
And just for your information. There's another place where you can filter the members - Quick Info tooltip. This is the place where you can filter out other members and display just methods — there are buttons at the bottom for this:


Thank you Peter.  I will use the Document Outline.

Hi Peter, my Document Outline Window is always empty now.  I was customizing the Settings in VS and perhaps unchecked something.  Is the Document Outline Window dependent on some Setting in Options?  Thank you.

@Axium7: Try Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced. Scroll to the very bottom and select Enable document outline

Thank you Peter.  That resolved it.  Much Appreciated.
